# Systemd and unnecessary process restarting

Tags: linux, systemd

I have a simple service written in Go lang. It starts web server with some business logic. Now we have to implement reload of this service. It is kill -HUP signal. By this signal initial process forks and serves connections in new process. Everything is nice but we want to use systemd for manage this service. And looks like systemd considers this as failure (initial process died) and after reload process restarts:

```
Aug 11 06:19:12 developmetn systemd[1]: my-proxy.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Aug 11 06:19:12 developmetn systemd[1]: Failed to start my-proxy image proxy
Aug 11 06:19:15 developmetn systemd[1]: my-proxy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 508.
Aug 11 06:19:15 developmetn systemd[1]: Stopped my-proxy image proxy.
Aug 11 06:19:15 developmetn systemd[1]: Starting my-proxy image proxy...
```

Obviously this kills idea to service 100% connections during reload. How to avoid this? We tried *Type=fork* option but systemctl reload  my-proxy.service command executes for ages.

```
[Unit]
Description=image proxy
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/my-proxy &
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/etc/my-proxy/
LimitNOFILE=infinity
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```